# Google Data Studio Calculatet Fields

Tags: looker-studio, calculated-field

is it possible to calculate like:

```
www.example.com + site
```

I want to add the Domain to the path, so that i can put a link of a specific page in the report.

Or is there a other way to show the Link of a site which should be reported?
THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a calculated field:

```
CONCAT(Hostname, Page)
```

That will give you the complete URL and, if you set the format to URL, it will work as a link.